# LPSTREAM Read entire Stream contents into unsigned char* array

Tags: c, file, winapi, stream, ole

I have a stream in a compound storage. I want to read its data into a byte array. I'm confused about what I need to put in the second parameter of lpSrc->Read(). I want to read the ENTIRE file into my unsigned char* (byte*) array:

```
        unsigned char* rawData;
        LPSTREAM lpSrc = NULL;
        HRESULT hrRet = STG_E_INVALIDPARAMETER;

        TRY
        { 
            USES_CONVERSION;
            HRESULT hrSrc = pStg->GetStg()->OpenStream(CT2COLE(szStream),
            NULL,
            STGM_READ | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE,
            0,
            &lpSrc);

            if (hrSrc != NOERROR)
            {
                hrRet = hrSrc;
            }
            else
            {               
                ULONG ul;
                hrRet = lpSrc->Read(rawData, /*???*/, &ul);             
            }

        }
        CATCH_ALL(e)
        {
            hrRet = STG_E_UNKNOWN;
        }
        END_CATCH_ALL
```

I've tried many variations on reading the stream, so I'm not entirely sure this is the way I should do it in the first place. How do i solve this problem?

Comment: You've allocated no memory for `rawData`.  I'd suggest the following.  Set `bytesRead` to 0 and set your `rawData` buffer to NULL.  *Do* the following: `realloc` your buffer to an appropriate size.  `Read` into your buffer at the appropriate offset and check the return value of `Read`.  Increment `bytesRead`. Loop *while* the return value indicates there is more data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm confused about what I need to put in the second parameter of lpSrc->Read().

The answer is in the documentation:

[ISequentialStream::Read method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380011.aspx)

> pv [out]
>
> A pointer to the buffer which the stream data is read into.
>
> cb [in]
>
> **The number of bytes of data to read from the stream object**.
>
> pcbRead [out]
>
> A pointer to a ULONG variable that receives the actual number of bytes read from the stream object.

You have to specify the number of bytes you want to read from the stream into your buffer.

> I want to read the ENTIRE file into my unsigned char* (byte*) array:

That means you have to know how many bytes are available in the stream in the first place.  You get that from the [`IStream::Stat()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380045.aspx) method.  Then you have to allocate your `rawData` buffer to that size before you can then read data into the buffer.

Try something like this:

```
#ifndef SIZE_MAX
#define SIZE_MAX ((size_t)(-1))
#endif

unsigned char* rawData;
LPSTREAM lpSrc = NULL;
HRESULT hrRet = STG_E_INVALIDPARAMETER;

TRY
{ 
    USES_CONVERSION;
    hrRet = pStg->GetStg()->OpenStream(
        CT2COLE(szStream),
        NULL,
        STGM_READ | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE,
        0,
        &lpSrc);

    if (hrRet == S_OK)
    {
        STATSTG stat;
        hrRet = lpSrc->Stat(&stat, STATFLAG_NONAME);
        if (hrRet == S_OK)
        {
            if (stat.cbSize.QuadPart > SIZE_MAX)
            {
                hrRet = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_TOO_LARGE);
            }
            else
            {
                size_t size = (size_t) stat.cbSize.QuadPart;

                rawData = malloc(size);
                if (!rawData)
                {
                    hrRet = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
                }
                else
                {
                    unsigned char *ptr = rawData;
                    size_t sizeLeft = size;

                    while (sizeLeft != 0)
                    {
                        ULONG ul;
                        hrRet = lpSrc->Read(ptr, (sizeLeft >= MAXDWORD) ? MAXDWORD : (DWORD) sizeLeft, &ul);             
                        if (FAILED(hrRet) || (ul == 0)) break;
                        ptr += ul;
                        sizeLeft -= ul;
                    }

                    if (SUCCEEDED(hrRet))
                    {
                        if (sizeLeft != 0) size -= sizeLeft;
                        // use rawData up to size number of bytes as needed...
                    }

                    free(rawData);
                }
            }
        }

        lpSrc->Release();
    }
}
CATCH_ALL(e)
{
    hrRet = E_UNEXPECTED;
}
END_CATCH_ALL
```

Comment: And note that if your file is larger than 4gb you are not going to be able to read it in one go no matter what you do.